# Merge 3 dataframes which are different to each other

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to merge 3 data frames which are different. I have one with few rows and another one with different Key.see the data frames below

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("12/03/2013","12/03/2013","12/03/2013"), f1 = c(189,256,389), f2 = c("NY","MB","LT"))
df2 <- data.frame(date = c("12/03/2013","12/03/2013"), Added_f1 = c(178,49), added_f2 = c("okr","nor"))
df3 <- data.frame(date = c("07/09/2016","07/09/2016","07/09/2016"), f1 = c(190,200,367), f5 = c("so","yo","kl"),f7 = c("sott","yogh","klop"))
```

I do want to merge them using the date as the key. I have tried these options but it generates an error of mismatch,  **must specify a uniquely valid* column*

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="date",all=TRUE) ,list(df1,df2,df3))
```

**Note** that column names can be different in each data frame. The second data frame can be merged on the right since columns are totally different but how can a third data frame be merged since the key is different and columns can have those matching and others which don't. I do want one table as a result.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show expected output for given example ?

Comment: df3 has the column nemed `dates`, not `date`. That is what the error message tells you: you don't have the column to merge

Comment: @denis should be date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you strictly only need to merge 3 data.frames, do it by hand:

```
merge(
  merge(df1,df2,by="date",all=TRUE),
  df3, by.x='date', by.y='dates', all=TRUE)
```

With `Reduce`, there isn't room for append additional arguments to each set. However, with a bit of repacking, we can do the following:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) {
    res <- merge(x$d, y$d, by.x=x$key, by.y=y$key, all=TRUE)
    list(key=x$key, d=res)
  }, 
  list(list(key='date', d=df1), list(key='date', d=df2), list(key='dates', d=df3))
)
```

Comment: df3 data frame column is  date, not dates. Sorry for typing error